# How to change Pseudo ::before element and ::after element using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a datetime picker calender, in which I need to modify some Pseudo elements,

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu.bottom:before {
    border-bottom: 7px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);              
    left: 7px;
}
```

This is my pseudo css, in which I need to modify left to 235px, but I really can't seem to do it using jquery.
Tried this without success,

```
if(selectedRow == noOfRows){
            $(".bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu.bottom:before").css({
               "left":"235px !important"
            });
            $(".bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu.bottom:after").css({
                "left":"235px !important"
            });
        }
```

Advice and knowledge is appreciated.

Comment: You should toggle a class instead as javascript/jQuery cannot target pseudo element. e.g: `.toggling-class.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu.bottom:before { left: 235px; }`. And then: `$(".bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu.bottom").addClass('toggling-class');`

Comment: Thanks buddy. It worked. :)